# Extract a text between two strings multiple times in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am using a google spreadsheet to extract specific values from a cell:
X: product 1;Y: product 2;Z: product 3

Expected output: X; Y; Z

I managed to extract only the first value: =iferror(regexextract(A1,".+?:.+?")

How can I run it several times?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(JOIN(";", REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, ";"), "(.+):")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We might be able to use a regex replace approach here:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "([A-Z]+):.*?(;|$)", "$1$2")
```

### Demo

Here we are matching and capturing the leading product letter(s) right before the colon.  We also match up to, and including, the nearest semicolon separator or the end of the cell.  We capture this optional semicolon, and then replace with just `$1$2`, which are the first two capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Why use regular expression if you need only the first character of each item:

```
=ArrayFormula(join(";",left(split(A1,";"),1)))
```